# Wrong zip command messed up my project directory

Tags: command-line, files, gzip

I've issued a command `gzip -r project.zip project/*` in projects home directory and I've messed things up; every file in project directory and all other subdirectories have `.gz` extension. How do I undo this operation, i.e., how do I remove `.gz` extension from script, so I do not need to rename every file by hand?

Comment: You didn't rename the file, you compressed them. So what you need to do now is not to rename the files, but to uncompress them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could go into said directory and use:

```
$ gunzip *.gz
```

For future reference, if you want to zip an entire directory, use

```
tar -zcvf project.tar.gz project/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `gunzip`.

`gunzip -r project/`